# Storing more than one array in another array

Tags: c#, arrays, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently using *ASP.NET Core MVC* for my application and I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Say I have two array of double type

```
double[] questionOne = {1,4,5,2,4};
double[] questionTwo = {3,2,4,5,2};
```

I want to use a method to concatenate them together and store them in possibly a dictionary such that the stored value is something like

```
stud1 | 1,3
stud2 | 4,2
stud3 | 5,4
stud4 | 2,5
stud5 | 4,2
```

so I can retrieve the values and calculate the total value for each student.

I *do not know* how many questions there will be. 
Neither do I know how many students there will be.

I'll be able to loop for these values later on but for now, its a fixed value.

Should I be storing the values in a dictionary, list or a tuple?

Thereafter, how can I call the method such that I can return the value and display in my "View"?
I don't need the values to be in a table, a simple raw output to check the algorithm idea will do if possible.

Comment: Maybe a dictionary of names and tuples?

Comment: Something like a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .Net 4.7 You can use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] questionOne = {1, 4, 5, 2, 4};
        double[] questionTwo = {3, 2, 4, 5, 2};
        var combined = questionOne.Zip(questionTwo, (q1, q2) => (q1, q2)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(combined);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm not using console for my application. Do you happen to know how do I pass it to my view? I've tried using ViewData but its not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<Tuple<double, double>> tuples =
    questionOne.Zip(questionTwo, (one, two) => Tuple.Create(one, two)).ToList();
```

That combines the number arrays. You can do the same for the students:

```
string[] students = new string[] {"stud1", "stud2", "stud3", "stud4", "stud5"};
Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, double>> result = students
    .Zip(tuples, (student, tuple) => new { student, tuple })
    .ToDictionary(entry => entry.student, entry => entry.tuple);
```

You can check out the result [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NAjyvv).

Comment: Thanks for replying! This method would be great if I knew the number of students and tests I have to loop through

Answer (score 0):

You could use this structure:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> myDictionary= new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

then you just need a algorithm which is adding the content like:

```
for(int i=0; i<array1.Length; i++) {
    String[] data = new String[2];
    data[0] = array1[i];
    data[1] = array1[i];
    myDictionary.Add("student"+i, data);
}
```